# How to join tables when the table to be chosen in content-dependent?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

Suppose you have a table called Shape as bellow:

```
Shape { id, name, type, user }
```

Then you have two other tables called Circle and Rectangle:

```
Circle { id, radius }
Rectangle { id, width, height }
```

If the user wants to get all information of a Shape with ID, he needs to first check the type of the Shape and then join with the corresponding shape (Circle or Rectangle)

Is it possible to do it in SQL?
Is this a valid table design at all?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. E.g using outer joins or union.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes it is possible to do it in SQL.

2) Yes it is valid table design.

As you have not specified which language and DB you are using, I am taking some liberty to explain my answer with SQL server and C#.

What you trying to achieve is a simple example of table inheritance. Where your `Shape` table would act as base table and `Circle` and `Rectangle` would act as child to `Shape` table. You can define this relation ship by declaring ID as primary key on `Shape` table while giving having ID column in child table as FK to `Shape` table and primary key in itself.

Now if you want to fetch all circles then you can query them using

```
select c.*, s.* from 
Circle c 
inner join Shape s on s.ID = c.ID
```

Discussing further, If you are using `Entity Framework` as your ORM you can choose one of the following strategies to define your database schema.

- Table per Hierarchy (TPH)
- Table per Type (TPT)
- Table per Concrete class (TPC)

I am leaving further detailed to [this document](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx).

**EDIT**

Identifying type using SQL queries will become tricky in such cases. You will have to write a lot of `CASE` and `UNION` statements to identify correct type.

But you can have an idea how ORMs such as `Entity Framework` identify types. I am taking reference from [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt).

Consider following are your entities and their respective tables.

[image]

Now if you fire EF query where you know type

```
var query = from b in context.BillingDetails.OfType<BankAccount>() select b;
```

It gets converted into following query.

[image]

But if you want to fetch all bank details (or query based on some id without specifying any type), underlying query gets converted something like this.

```
var query = from b in context.BillingDetails select b;
```

Generated Query:

[image]

So if you intend to use it without any ORM provider, it would become a little bit trickier identifying types.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. And what if the user needs to fetch all shapes with a particular ID=3 and he does not know if it is Circle or Rectangle? How can I deal with this switch case ? I need to check the type first, and make a query based on the type of the shape?

Answer (score 1):

As already answered, yes to both questions. But, because I can be quite anal about data integrity, I would make the following design suggestions:

```
create table Shape(
    ID       int not null primary key auto_generate,
    Type     char( 1 ) not null,
    Name     varchar( xx ),
    User     varchar( xx ),
    ..., -- other common shape-related attributes
    constraint CK_Shape_Type check Type in( 'C', 'R' ),
    constraint UQ_Shape_ID_Type unique( ID, Type )
);
```

Now you may ask, "If ID is a primary key, it must be unique all by itself. Why create a unique constraint using the PK and another field?"

Answer: So we can enforce the shape continuity across the sub-tables.

```
create table Circle(
    ID       int not null primary key,
    Type     char( 1 ) not null,
    Radius   numeric,
    CenterX  numeric,
    CenterY  numeric,
    ..., -- other circle-related attributes
    constraint CK_Circle_Type check Type = 'C',
    constraint FK_Circle_Shape foreign key( ID, Type )
        references Shape( ID, Type )
);

create table Rectangle(
    ID       int not null primary key,
    Type     char( 1 ) not null,
    Width    numeric,
    Length   numeric,
    ..., -- other rectangle-related attributes
    constraint CK_Rectangle_Type check Type = 'R',
    constraint FK_Rectangle_Shape foreign key( ID, Type )
        references Shape( ID, Type )
);
```

Now the Circle table can contain only circles and the Rectangle table can contain only rectangles and it is impossible to define, say, a Rectangle with an ID that has been defined as a Circle in the Shape table or vice versa.

Another suggestion is that you always keep the ID and Type values together as part of the identifier of the parts in your application. That way you will always be able to identify the circles and the rectangles without going out to the Shapes table. You could even define ID and Type as the composite PK of the Circle and Rectangle tables -- but *not* the Shape table.

You could also have a different view for each shape that would combine the common Shape data and the shape-specific data. So your app, knowing it is working with a Rectangle just goes out and reads every attribute from the Rectangle view.